# What does the "..." mean in a parameter list? doInBackground(String... params)

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I don't understand that syntax.  Trying to google various words plus "..." is useless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, 3 dots in parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called [Variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (wiki page with examples in many languges).

> In computer programming, a variadic
>   function is a function of indefinite
>   arity, i.e. one which accepts a
>   variable number of arguments. Support
>   for variadic functions differs widely
>   among programming languages. There are
>   many mathematical and logical
>   operations that come across naturally
>   as variadic functions. For instance,
>   the summing of numbers or the
>   concatenation of strings or other
>   sequences are operations that can
>   logically apply to any number of
>   operands. Another operation that has
>   been implemented as a variadic
>   function in many languages is output
>   formatting. The C function printf and
>   the Common Lisp function format are
>   two such examples. Both take one
>   argument that specifies the formatting
>   of the output, and any number of
>   arguments that provide the values to
>   be formatted. Variadic functions can
>   expose type-safety problems in some
>   languages. For instance, C's printf,
>   if used incautiously, can give rise to
>   a class of security holes known as
>   format string attacks. The attack is
>   possible because the language support
>   for variadic functions is not
>   type-safe; it permits the function to
>   attempt to pop more arguments off the
>   stack than were placed there --
>   corrupting the stack and leading to
>   unexpected behavior. Variadic
>   functionality can be considered
>   complementary to the apply function,
>   which takes a function and a
>   list/sequence/array as arguments and
>   then calls the function once, with the
>   arguments being the elements of the
>   list.

One of may **personal favorite** not used features in **Java**. It is basically a reference array that is built from elements. One of the best ways to use it is on class constructor, or method where you need to constantly find a value like maximum of 2, 3, 4, 5 input elements.

One example is, when i built a generic [`binary tree node`](http://pastebin.com/GutNKbzr), for coding tasks, I used this in constructor. This enabled me simply add elements to the tree and distribute them.

Following creates String type binary tree, with root `"Red"` and 2 branches `"Blue"` and `"Green"`.

```
new MBTN<String>("Red", "Blue", "Green").
```

Could you think what the alternatives would be :D You can't even simply make generic array of elements, so this would stretch like hell. It is definitely not useless.

Comment: Thanks all. I totally understand.  I guess not knowing this I would have just used a String[] in its place.  But now I can read the code others write.

Comment: "You can't even simply make generic array of elements" Then you will get a warning when using varargs in this way, because it will also try to create a generic array behind the scenes, but can't

Comment: I should mention, that **new MBTN<String>(Arrays.asList("Red", "Blue", "Green"));** would be considered better.

Answer (score 19):

It's called [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). This fact should yield [better Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+varargs).

Answer (score 14):

They are the "variable arguments" or varargs (for short).

Basically it allows the passing of an unspecified number of Strings, so the method signature

```
public void printStuff(String...messages)
```

Effectively can handle the following calls

```
printStuff("hi");
printStuff("hi", "bye");
printStuff("Hello", "How are you?", "I'm doing fine.", "See you later");
```

You can effectively consider this a type of autoboxing.  The `printStuff` argument can be seen as an array, so `printStuff(String...messages)` is conceptually handled like `printStuff(String[] messages)`.  Wtih the calls above effectively acting like

```
printStuff(new String[] {"hi"});
printStuff(new String[] {"hi", "bye"});
printStuff(new String[] {"Hello", "How are you?", "I'm doing fine.", "See you later"});
```

To access the messages internally, you use typical `List` handling primitives.  Something like

```
...
if (messages != null) {
  for (String message : messages) {
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}
...
```

That there is no need to actually create arrays is a bit of syntactic sugar added to Java with the advent of auto boxing.

Comment: Hi i'm passing only one parameter, how to access that one.

Comment: @Sridhar When passing only one parameter, it becomes the first (and only) element in the array.

Comment: Thanks for reply i got it. we can get the first argument as messages[0].

Answer (score 4):

As @BalusC mentioned, it's a varags parameter.  This means you can pass a variable number of arguments to that method.

So for a method defined as

```
public void foo(String...strings) {  }
```

The following invocations are legal:

```
foo();
foo("one param");
foo("one", "two", "three");
```

Answer (score 1):

They are variable length parameters.

Here is one link with an [example.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by everyone...variable arguments (or varargs) allows you to do this....

```
//Method we're using for varargs
public void doSomething(String... datas) {
    if (datas == null || datas.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("We got nothing");
    } else {
        for (String data: datas) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, all these calls mentioned below are valid....

```
String d[] = {"1", "2", "3"};
doSomething(d); //An array of String, as long as the type is exactly as the varargs type.

//OR
doSomething("1", "2", "3", "4"); //I can add "infinitely" many arguments as the JVM can allocate me....

//OR 
doSomething("1"); //Exactly 1;
```

Internally varargs is "essentially" a reference array of it's declared type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a java method that took an arbitrary variable number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

It means "Arbitrary number of arguments" meaning you can pass a unknown number of parameters into the method..

see

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html
Look for the "Arbitrary number of arguments" section

```
public Polygon polygonFrom(Point... corners) {
    int numberOfSides = corners.length;
    double squareOfSide1, lengthOfSide1;
    squareOfSide1 = (corners[1].x - corners[0].x)*(corners[1].x - corners[0].x) 
            + (corners[1].y - corners[0].y)*(corners[1].y - corners[0].y) ;
    lengthOfSide1 = Math.sqrt(squareOfSide1);
    // more method body code follows that creates 
    // and returns a polygon connecting the Points
}
```