# String... keys in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java, 3 dots in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters)

In [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) the are using the construct `String... keys`(this is something new??)

For example this method

```
jedis.blpop(int timeout, String... keys);
```

I believe you can use this as both a String as an array. How can I use this in my code(example)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters

Comment: It was added in Java 5.0 in 2004. So it is new-ish. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are Java's [variadic arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

You could pass an array of strings or a bunch of `String` objects.

Passing a `String[]` array.

```
String sarr[] = {"key1", "key2", "key3"};
jedis.blpop(someTimeout, sarr);
```

Passing several `String` objects separately:

`jedis.blpop(someTimeout, "key1", "key2", "key3")`

Answer (score 0):

See [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) in the Java Tutorial.