# What is the meaning of the three dots in a method declaration?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java, 3 dots in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters)

```
public static void getImages(String... folders) throws IOException{

}
```

In the above `getImages()` method, why there is three dots. What is it mean? I searched google but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, punctuation is hard to search for if you don't know the technical term. In this case, it is *varargs*. [Here](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/645-varargs-in-java-50/) is a nice link to explain it. Basically, the caller can add as many arguments as desired, and the method sees them arriving as an array of that length.

Comment: A fancier term is "variadic function".