# what does the three dots in "doInBackground(URL... urls)" mean?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

what does the "..." in each function mean? and why in the last function, there is no "..."?

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Read Here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[As Morrison said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665783/119114), the `...` syntax is for a *variable* length list of arguments (`urls` holds more than one `URL`).

This is typically used to allow users of the `AsyncTask` to do things like (in your case) pass in more than one URL to be fetched in the background.  If you only have one URL, you would use your `DownloadFilesTask` like this:

```java
DownloadFilesTask worker = new DownloadFilesTask();
worker.execute(new URL("http://google.com"));
```

or with multiple URLs, do this:

```java
worker.execute(new URL[]{ new URL("http://google.com"), 
                          new URL("http://stackoverflow.com") });
```

The `onProgressUpdate()` is used to let the background task communicate progress to the UI.  Since the background task might involve **multiple** jobs (one for each URL parameter), it may make sense to publish separate progress values (e.g. 0 to 100% complete) for each task.  You don't have to.  Your background task could certainly choose to calculate a **total** progress value, and pass that single value to `onProgressUpdate()`.

The `onPostExecute()` method is a little different.  It processes a **single** result, from the set of operations that were done in `doInBackground()`.  For example, if you download multiple URLs, then you might return a failure code if **any** of them failed.  The input parameter to `onPostExecute()` will be whatever value you **return** from `doInBackground()`.  That's why, in this case, they are both `Long` values.

If `doInBackground()` returns `totalSize`, then that value will be passed on `onPostExecute()`, where it can be used to inform the user what happened, or whatever other post-processing you like.

If you really need to communicate multiple *results* as a result of your background task, you can certainly change the `Long` generic parameter to something other than a `Long` (e.g. some kind of collection).

Answer (score 4):

In Java its called Varargs which allow for a variable number of parameters.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 2):

The three dots are `...` are used to indicate [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), In our case in Java Language these are used to indicate [varangs](http://www.javatpoint.com/varargs) (variable no. of arguments).

Let me explain a little bit about [varangs](http://www.javatpoint.com/varargs):

> The [varangs](http://www.javatpoint.com/varargs) allows the method to accept zero or muliple
>   arguments.If we don't know how many argument we will have to pass in
>   the method, varargs is the better approach.

**Syntax of varargs:**

The [varargs](http://www.javatpoint.com/varargs) uses [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) i.e. three dots after the data type. Syntax is as follows:

> `return_type method_name(data_type... variableName){}`

**Simple Example of Varargs in java:**

```
class VarargsExample1{  

 static void display(String... values){  
  System.out.println("display method invoked ");  
 }  

 public static void main(String args[]){  

 display();//zero argument   
 display("my","name","is","varargs");//four arguments  
 }   
}
```

> **Rules for varargs:**
>
> While using the varargs, you must follow some rules otherwise program
>   code won't compile. The rules are as follows:
>
> There can be only one variable argument in the method. Variable
>   argument (varargs) must be the last argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Very short (and basic) answer:**
That represents a variable number of items "converted" to an array and it should be the last argument.
Example:

```
test("string", false, 20, 75, 31);

void test(String string, boolean bool, int... integers) {
    // string = "string"
    // bool = false
    // integers[0] = 20
    // integers[1] = 75
    // integers[2] = 31
}
```

But you can also call

`test("text", true, 15);`

or

`test("wow", true, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 123, 345, 9123);`