# Java 3 dots parameter (varargs) behavior when passed no arguments or null

Tags: java, variadic-functions, ellipsis

I tried this and get weird behavior from JAVA, can someone explain this for me?

```
boolean testNull(String... string) {
    if(string == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(string.getClass());
        return false;
    }
}

boolean callTestNull(String s) {
    return testNull(s);
}
```

Then I have test case:

```
    @Test
    public void test_cases() {
        assertTrue(instance.testNull(null)); // NULL
        assertFalse(instance.testNull()); // NOT NULL
        assertFalse(instance.callTestNull(null)); // NOT NULL
    }
```

The question is if I call `testNull()` directly with parameter `null`, I will get `true` back, but if call `callTestNull()` with `null`, which calls `testNull()`, it tells me the parameter is not null, but empty array.

Comment: How do you find that array is empty?

Comment: I meant in terms of Java terminology. But yes, the character "..." is indeed called ellipsis. More info on programming use here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(programming_operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, 3 dots in parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> The question is if I call testNull() directly with parameter null, I will get true back, but if call callTestNull() with null, which calls testNull(), it tells me the parameter is not null, but empty array.

Yes. If you call it with an argument with a *compile-time type* of `String`, the compiler knows that *can't* be a `String[]`, so it wraps it within a string array. So this:

```
String x = null;
testNull(x);
```

is equivalent to:

```
String x = null;
testNull(new String[] { x });
```

At this point, the (misleadingly-named) `string` parameter will have a non-null value - instead, it will refer to an array of size 1 whose sole element is a null reference.

However, when you use the `null` literal directly in the method call, that's directly convertible to `String[]`, so no wrapping is performed.

From [JLS section 15.12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2):

> If the method being invoked is a variable arity method m, it necessarily has n > 0 formal parameters. The final formal parameter of m necessarily has type T[] for some T, and m is necessarily being invoked with k ≥ 0 actual argument expressions.
>
> If m is being invoked with k ≠ n actual argument expressions, or, if m is being invoked with k = n actual argument expressions **and the type of the k'th argument expression is not assignment compatible with T[]**, then the argument list (e1, ..., en-1, en, ..., ek) is evaluated as if it were written as (e1, ..., en-1, new |T[]| { en, ..., ek }), where |T[]| denotes the erasure (§4.6) of T[].

(Emphasis mine.)

The bit I've emphasized is why the wrapping *only* happens when the compile-time type of the argument is `String`, not the null type.