# What does int[]... arrays mean in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Can you help me? What does int[]... arrays mean in Java?
Example:

```
public static int[] concat(int[]... arrays) {
int length = 0;
for (int[] array : arrays) {
    length += array.length;
}
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: Or here: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Declare.htm
Sounds like you need to start right from the start. I googled that in seconds by the way. You should do the same.

Comment: it's same as `int[][]`

Answer (score 4):

That is called [`varargs.. notation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html),

So that you can pass individual `int[]` objects to that method,, without worrying of no.of arguments.

When you write

```
public static int[] concat(int[]... arrays) {
```

Now you can use that method like

```
Classname.concat(array1,array2,array3)   //example1
Classname.concat(array1,array2)    //example2
Classname.concat(array1,array2,array3,array4)   //example3
```

A clear benefit is you need not to prepare an array to pass a method. You can pass values of that array directly.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the `concat` function can receive zero or more arrays of integers (`int[]`). That's why you can loop over the `arrays` argument, accessing one of the arrays contained in each iteration - if any. This is called [variable arguments (or `varargs`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This means, that you can pass zero, one or more arrays of int (`int[]`) to your method. Consider following example

```
public void method(String ... strings)
```

can be called as

- `method()`
- `method("s")`
- `method("s", "d")`
- ...

So your method can be called as

- `concat()`
- `concat(new int[0])`
- `concat(new int[0], new int[0])`
- ...

Answer (score 1):

This means that you can pass the method [any number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) of `int[]` objects:

```
concat(new int[]{1,2});
concat(new int[]{1,2}, new int[]{3,4,5});
concat(new int[]{1}, new int[]{3,4,5,6}, new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,1,1});
```

Why this is useful? It's clear why :)

Answer (score 0):

The `...` is the most important part, it means you can have an unlimited amount of integers passed in and it is just accessed via the array, so you could call it as:

`concat(1,2,3,4,5)` or `concat(1)`

Most languages have this sort of feature, some call it var args others call it params.

Answer (score 0):

varargs ("...") notation basically informs that the arguments may be passed as a sequence of arguments (here - ints) or as an array of arguments. In your case, as your argument is of type "array of int", it means arguments may be passed as a sequence of arrays or as an array of arrays of int (note that array of arrays is quite equivalent to multidimensional array in Java).

Answer (score 0):

For example you have a method:

```
void functionName (Object objects...)
{
  Object object1=objects[0];
  Object object2=objects[1];
  Object object3=objects[2];
}
```

You can use your method as:

```
Object object1,object2,object3;

functionName(object1,object2,object3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Using Variable Arguments](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/04/19/varargs.html)**

The ellipsis (...) identifies a variable number of arguments, and
is demonstrated in the following summation method.

```
public static int[] concat(int[]... arrays)
```

Use method

```
concat(val1, val2, val3);
concat(val1, val2, val3, val3);
```