# How to pass string arguments to AsyncTask in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This must be really easy but I am stuck now for an hour or so. I am passing `String[]` to an `AsyncTask` class as such

```
class test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Again, use either params local to this function
        // or args local to the entire function... 
        // both would be redundant
        String _NAMESPACE = params[0];
        String _METHODNAME = params[1];
        String _SOAPACTION = params[2];
        String _USER_NAME = params[3];
        String _USER_PASS= params[4];

        // Do background stuff
    }
}
```

I am sending my arguments as such

```
test t = new test();
String[] s = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
t.execute(s);
```

This is not working. How would I pass multiple `String` objects is my question. If I pass one string it works but if I try to pass them in an array it fails. btw I don't want to change the string parameter of the `AsyncTask` class to `String[]` because it would break my other code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the type that you declared in your method parameter actually match one of the generic parameters?

Comment: You are telling `onPostExecute()` to expect a `String` with the third `param` there. Which means, you should be returning a `String` in `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple Objects to this AsyncTask you can create a constructor to match them.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
    {
        public AsyncFileExists(Integer num1, Integer num2, String s, Boolean b) {
            super();
            // Do something with these parameters
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
```

And then just do

```
MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask(5, 10, "a string", false);
```

Comment: You can also just the same thing here with a blank constructor and define a method to populate a class array of strings that is saved in MyAsyncTask and used by doInBackground.

Comment: There are many possibilities. I like this one because you create the AsyncTask passing parameters from a Main class with only one line of code

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not working? Pardon, if I am missing something!

```
String[] s = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
String[] s1 = new String[]{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
```

both result in `[a, b, c, d, e]`

In `doInBackground(String... params)` you are expecting `String varargs`. So you can basically pass `zero or more` `String` objects (or an `array` of them) as the parameter(s) for your function `doInBackground`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters).

[image]

Comment: Thanx everyone. I edited my question now so the third parameter matches the return value. For the answer though, I picked @Teo's response for simplicity. I am loving this site by the day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
t.execute(string1, string2, string3, string4);  // as many as you want..
```

that's the simplest way of passing more than one `String` arguments to `AsyncTask`

Comment: I consider a string array semantically different than multiple string parameters.  Just sayin'.

Comment: agreed, and you are right as usual... I put that answer based on the fact that this will help OP in getting his results with easiest way...