# When varargs started to not conflict with no-arg?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Today I found that the following code compiles and runs with no any warning:

```
public class Try_MultipleArguments2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        myfunction();

        myfunction(1, 2, 3);

    }

    public static void myfunction(int ... as) {
        System.out.println("varags called");
    }

    public static void myfunction() {
        System.out.println("noarg called");
    }
}
```

I am remembering clear, that it was not so earlier.

Is this JVM change or my memory glitch???

How it distinguish between no-arg and varargs?

**UPDATE**

The following code also runs ok:

```
public class Try_MultipleArguments2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        myfunction();

        myfunction(1, 2, 3);

    }

    public static void myfunction(int ... as) {
        System.out.println("varags called");
    }

//    public static void myfunction() {
//        System.out.println("noarg called");
//    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside from the Oracle Technotes: ["Generally speaking, you should not overload a varargs method, or it will be difficult for programmers to figure out which overloading gets called."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Was it causing warning or error some time ago?

Comment: I don't know, I just wanted to point out that Oracle themselves advise you not to do it.

Comment: I was never doing this and as result found that I was not knowing something!

Comment: Yeah, it's alright, dude, I just wanted to point out some piece of advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are overloaded methods. The compiler knows which method the compiled `main` shoulld call from the method signature. See [this specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> When a method is invoked (§15.12), the number of actual arguments (and any explicit type arguments) and the compile-time types of the arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the method that will be invoked (§15.12.2).

Furthermore, the method chosen is the one that is *most specific*. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). In this case, the no-arg method is more specific than the varargs version - again the number of parameters is checked to see which method to choose..

Comment: Why is it calling no-arg version in first call? It is indistinguisheable from varargs with zero parameters.

Comment: Was this ambiguity causing error or warning some time ago?

Comment: No. This code would compile fine in JDK1.5. Varargs were introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score -2):

Its function overloading at backend.

Your `void myfunction(int ... as)`  is accepting multiple arguments while your  `void myfunction()` has no  argument. I don't see any glitch in this . [Method Overloading](http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java)

Comment: you are updating the question and downvoting answers based on your previous  question.. Don't make sense..

Comment: You know people other than the asker can downvote answers too, right? From the phrasing it's apparent that the asker already knows what overloading is, but he is wondering why and how this work and if it has always been this way. Your question does not even touch on the question, hence the downvote.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your answer itself does not explain method overloading very well and mainly links to an off-site resource which is discouraged.

Comment: I was not downvoting anybody :)

Comment: If you downvote someone you must provide the reason the same time which the downvoter didn't. The answerer must know why his answer was not liked,etc. Its good that I got some reasons now.

Comment: One can downvote whenever they feel it is appropriate. The downvote box asks you **to consider** adding an explanation, it's by no means an obligation. I didn't need to explain my downvote, I did it out of fairness to you.