# Passing List<String> to String... parameter

Tags: java, android, arrays, variadic-functions

I'm struggling to pass a List of Strings into a method requiring the parameter "**String...**".

Can anybody help me out?

```
// How to put names into dummyMethod?
List<String> names = getNames();
```

---

```
 public void dummyMethod(String... parameter) {
    mInnerList.addAll(Arrays.asList(parameter));
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll have to convert the `List<String>` to a String array in order to use it in the 'varargs' parameter of `dummyMethod`. You can use [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) with an extra array as parameter. Otherwise, the method returns an `Object[]` and it won't compile:

```
List<String> names = getNames();
dummyMethod(names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following :

```
dummyMethod(names.toArray(new String[names.size()])
```

this will convert the list to array

Answer (score 3):

Pass String array (`String[]`) inside method. You will have to convert your List to Array and then pass it.

```
if (names != null) {
    dummyMethod(names.toArray(new String[names.size()])); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is vararg parameter and for this you should pass array. ArrayList won't work. You can rather convert this list to array before passing to the method.

```
String a = new String[names.size];
list.toArray(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you later parse the parameter as a List, I suggest changing the method to:

```
public void dummyMethod(List<String> parameter) {
    mInnerList.addAll(parameter);
}
```

to avoid the extra costs.

However, if you want to use this method "as it is", then you should call it like that:

```
dummyMethod(names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));
```

as Glorfindel suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32223259/2516301), 
since the three dots mean that you can call the method using many Strings, or an array of Strings (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters) for more details).

Comment: `toArray()` will return an `Object[]` - this won't compile.

Comment: Thanks. toArray() (and some extra casting) did it! The method with "String..." parameter is part of a library, so I was trying to avoid changing it. But that would have been my next attempt to solve it.

Comment: @Glorfindel I was updating my answer when you commented, after seeing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The var-arg actually accepts an array and you can use it like:

```
dummyMethod(names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));
```

Here is a sample code:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("A");
names.add("B");
dummyMethod(names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));
```