# Can I pass list of strings as a parameter to Controller's Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement something like this:

```
public ActionResult ListOfErrors(List<string> listOfErrors)
{
     somelogic;
}

public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    List<string> newList = new List<string>(){"aaaa","bbbb","cccc"};
    return RedirectToAction("ListOfErrors", newList);
}
```

But `listOfErrors` in Action `ListOfErrors` is a 1 item list with value: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Can it be done?

EDIT: I've changed route values based on suggestion on comments but in redirected Action I get null in a List parameter.

Comment: Just strip the `new {}` wrapper where you're passing the `newList` to the redirect?

Comment: Just `return RedirectToAction("ListOfErrors", newList)` should do :)

Comment: There is a progress, it's null now. So do you know what could I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might require foreach loop to iterate each and every member of your list.
You need something like:

```
foreach ( var item in newList )
   {
       //Your Logic

   }
```

Yes! you can pass a list of strings as a parameter to Controller's Action

Check these Links:

[Passing-Liststring-to-string-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223161/passing-liststring-to-string-parameter)

[Convert List string](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string)