# Can any one explain me this syntax of predefined GenericModel class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Can any one explain me this syntax of predefined GenericModel class?Here what is Object... what are these 3 dots(period) for can any one explain me.

```
public static JPAQuery find(String query, Object... params) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Please annotate your JPA     model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.");
        }
```

Comment: Read the part about Arbitrary Number of Arguments in the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object... params` means zero or more objects of type `java.lang.Object` may be passed as the parameter(s) for the method `find`.

Please refer to the official tutorials on **[Arbitrary Number of Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs)**.

See also: **[Java, 3 dots in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters)**.

Comment: Thank you @Sandeep Chatterjee