# I cannot add an object to an ArrayList by given Argument in method

Tags: java

I want to make a simulation of a queueing system in Java.

```
public void enqueue(Packet...packets)
{ 
  // here the Packet object needs to be added to an existing ArrayList..

}
```

I tried to add the Packet as follows in my existing Arraylist `queue`

```
queue.add(packets)
```

but this doesn't work.

How can I best do this ? I can't give an `ArrayList` as argument, it has to be `Packet...packets`.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that "but it doesn't work" you mean, you want to add each packet to a separate entry of your array.

you can iterate through your array and add one packet at a time.

```
public void enqueue(Packet...packets)
{ 
  for(Packet packet : packets){
    queue.add(packet);
  }
}
```

NOTE:

`Packet... packets` (more or less) is another way of saying `Packet[] packets`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Packets... is an array. 
Please try:

```
queueList.addAll(Arrays.asList(packets));
```

Comment: Nit: you don't "have to use" this; it is merely a convenient way to do it.