# SImple AsyncTask that returns int

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm very new to programming. I have a program that has lots and lots of methods that run consecutively to each other. My application freezes until its done calculating.  I want to put everything in AsyncTask but I'm having a really hard time understanding how it works.

This is what I have so far as a separate java file.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ConvertToStringToIntt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... timeString) {
        String time = timeString;
        time = time.replace(":","");
        int value = -2;
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(time);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Message.message(this, "String time could not be converted to int");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

This method basically takes in a String of time and returns it as an int.  But I am getting an error in `String time = timeString`;

says:

> Incompatible types  Required: java.lang.String Found:
>   java.lang.String[]

I don't know what that means.  Any help would be great, and thank you.

Comment: timeString is an Array of String, if you send 1 string upon executing the AsyncTask, then use String time = timeString[0];

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters for an explanation of the `String...` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach, and if you are sure of passing just a string //irrespective of business logic

```
public class ConvertToStringToIntt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... timeString) {
        String time = timeString[0];
        time = time.replace(":","");
        int value = -2;
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(time);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Message.message(this, "String time could not be converted to int");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it doInBackground sets arrays, that worked.  The int value will always return a simple int.  I currently access the AsyncTask in the MainActivity, how can I get that int into a variable in the MainActivity.                                                                ConvertToString convertToString = new ConvertToString();
     int i = convertToString.execute(getTimeString); does not work.