# Although constructor needs arguments i can still call it without them

Tags: java, constructor, variadic-functions

```
public class DenseVector extends AbstractVector implements Vector {

  public DenseVector(int n) { .. } 

  public DenseVector(Vector v) { .. }

  public DenseVector(double... elements) { .. }

}
```

Why can I call a constructor with variadic arguments without arguments?

```
DenseVector v = new DenseVector() // calls DoubleVector(double... elements)
```

`AbstractVector` has no manually provided constructors at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I call a constructor with variadic arguments without arguments?

You don't have the default constructor (it won't be generated) and the vararg constructor is the only option (it takes `[0, n]` `double`s - you passed none).

> ```
> DenseVector v = new DenseVector();
> ```

To call the no-arg constructor (if it was your intention), you have to define it first.

> `AbstractVector` has no manually provided constructors at all

That's why you shouldn't have written `super(...)` in all the constructors referring to a non-default parent constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Variadic arguments take **any number** of arguments. Including none.

If you want **one or more**, a common (slightly clumsy) pattern is

```
public DenseVector(double element, double... moreElements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variadic parameter allows a function (constructor in your case) to accept any number of arguments. Even if no argument is provided, the same function can be called.

Answer (score 0):

variadic constructors can be called with any number of args **(including 0 )**
take a look 
[Java, 3 dots in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters/10549763)

Answer (score 0):

As Java Language Specification states [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2):

*If the method being invoked is a variable arity method `m`, it necessarily has `n > 0` formal parameters. The final formal parameter of `m` necessarily has type  `T[]` for some `T`, and 
`m` is necessarily being invoked with k **≥** 0 actual argument expressions.*

**k ≥ 0**, means that you can pass 0 actual arguments to that method.