# JavaFX KeyFrame Instantiation

Tags: javafx, keyframe

I am relatively new to JavaFX. I have chosen the game "BrickBreaker", which is included as an example in NetBeans, to help me understand JavaFX.

The following code is from class `Splash`:

```
KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Config.ANIMATION_TIME, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

           //some code …
        });
```

My question is: is it possible to instantiate a `KeyFrame` without passing any instance of `KeyValue` to its constructor ?

The documentation shows five versions of the constructor [HERE](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html), and they all have a `KeyValue` argument, while the above code does not.

Comment: what happened when you tried :)

Comment: @kleopatra the game is working perfectly. But my question remains. As a developer, the documentation should be my #1 reference. Check the link in my question, no match to the constructor used in the code snippet. confusing, right ?!

Comment: Related: [Java, 3 dots in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730). Four of the five constructors use `KeyValue...` which is a _varargs_ parameter. The constructor call in your example passes a `Duration`, `EventHandler`, and a `KeyValue[]` of length `0` as arguments.

Comment: Indeed it's completely fine to not pass any values to a varargs parameter. The constructor your code uses is this one: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.util.Duration,javafx.event.EventHandler,javafx.animation.KeyValue...) (note that many IDEs provide info about the signature of the method/constructor invoked; this could be used to your advantage, if you're unsure about things like this.)

Comment: as developers, we should refresh our basic language knowledge regularly :)

Comment: @kleopatra I think we both (me & you) just did :)

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of all those looking for an answer to this question, and to make this question appear as answered in searches, I am answering my own question by quoting SLAW comment:

Related: [Java, 3 dots in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters). Four of the five constructors use `KeyValue...` which is a varargs parameter. The constructor call in your example passes a `Duration`, `EventHandler`, and a `KeyValue[]` of length `0` as arguments.