# What does "..." mean in Java

Tags: java

Really simple question but it's hard to Google and get an answer.

```java
  ApiFuture<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getAll(@Nonnull DocumentReference... documentReferences);
```

What does the operator `...` do after DocumentReference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java, 3 dots in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters)

Comment: Thanks yes it does - it's equivalent of _* in Scala.