# why do I get error if I remove the dots between int and number?

Tags: java

//what does the trailing dots mean?

```
static void add(int...numbers) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int num:numbers)
    {
        if(sum !=0){
            System.out.print("+");
        }
        sum+=num;
        System.out.print(num);
    }
    System.out.println("="+sum);
}
```

Comment: You are expected to put some effort into your post (there's [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) for a reason). If you don't, folks have no reason to put effort into answering.

Comment: because 'int...numbers' is an array, if you remove the dots will be just a simple 'int' and you can't iterate an 'int'

Comment: [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Have a look : [varargs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/what-do-3-dots-next-to-a-parameter-type-mean-in-java)

Comment: `...` basically mean`varargs` that is a collection/arrays of value

Answer (score 0):

> why do I get error if I remove the dots between int and number?

The dots say that this is a "varargs" parameter; i.e. you can have multiple values; see [What do 3 dots next to a parameter type mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730)

As a consequence, the actual type of `numbers` in your example is `int[]` within the method body.

So, when you remove the `...`, the type changes to `int`.  And that means that

```
    for(int num:numbers)
```

is invalid because an single `int` is not iterable.